# How to stream my video via websockets

Tags: html, ffmpeg, video-streaming, media

I am using Windows 8.1 OS.
I use ffmpeg to stream from my IP camera to my localhost.

This is the command I use:

```
ffmpeg  -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.12:554/video_4 -f mpeg1video -b 800k -r 30 http://localhost:8082/yourpassword/640/4800/
```

How can I 'capture' this stream in my IIS ASP.NET app?
Then how can I send the stream to my connected clients?  Do I have to use web sockets?

Is there working sample I can look at?

Thanks